# Typescript requirement to pass all variables

Tags: typescript

i Work with ts-jest and i trie to mock one service function but i only need pass one variable values of many others.
like the exemple below:

```
getDataInformationMocked.mockReturnValueOnce({
      scopes: ['local','cloud']
    });
```

this code works, but ts show a error saing it is more variables that are not being passed.

error message: **The type '{ scopes: string[]; }' does not have the following properties of type 'dataNames': iss, exp, nbf, aud and 20 more.**

so,
is there any way to pass all variables from an interface, without having to create an object with all values?

Comment: Can you share the full error message?

Comment: yes, i update the question with error msg

Comment: I wanted to pass these variables without having to create an obj with 20 other variables that I will not use, do something similar to spread

Comment: I did a reproduction here, is this an accurate recreation of the error? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAcnAthAZ2QG8AoZC5AhAewAdCAuKsKUAcwG0BdAbnMrACBZgVYd+lZBAAedUeJDtJlEACMYCtkpUU4AVwAmWiaQC+pUrRBjk7CGHSYAkiBg0ouDMBogAsjQIANYQhsgAvCQCFLiBQQBKDvpQIABqcAA2+hAA8iBIzAAUAPqGGNh4TGjlOPgEAJTMAG40wGHhAHwkFmb8pPaO5a7unt6+AcGhAHSxwYlgyWmZ2XlIhWRS1PRVnADkGYGZuwA0uwgHRrvc5vV9lkA

Comment: yes, this is the error

Comment: Are you able to modify the `DataNames` interface? You could make `iss`, `exp`, etc optional by adding a question mark: `iss?: string`. The problem is that you aren't providing values for those extra interface properties, and they will come into the function as undefined

Comment: Explain your problem clearly with correct a grammar.

Comment: @CharlesFries I've used your TS playground as a basis in my answer, thanks for adding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This builds off the playground provided by Charles Fries and both solutions resolve the error.

You can use either [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) which `Constructs a type with all properties of Type set to optional. This utility will return a type that represents all subsets of a given type.`:

```js
interface DataNames {
    scopes: string[];
    iss: string;
    exp: string;
    nbf: string;
    aud: string;
}

const getDataInformationMocked = {
    mockReturnValueOnce: (_dataNames: Partial<DataNames>): void => {}
};

getDataInformationMocked.mockReturnValueOnce({
    scopes: ['local','cloud']
});
```

Or [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) which `Constructs a type by picking the set of properties Keys (string literal or union of string literals) from Type.`:

```js
interface DataNames {
    scopes: string[];
    iss: string;
    exp: string;
    nbf: string;
    aud: string;
}

const getDataInformationMocked = {
    mockReturnValueOnce: (_dataNames: Pick<DataNames, 'scopes'>): void => {}
};

getDataInformationMocked.mockReturnValueOnce({
    scopes: ['local','cloud']
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a type assertion:

```js
getDataInformationMocked.mockReturnValueOnce({
  scopes: ['local','cloud']
} as dataNames);
```